# Joining with NULL values

Tags: mysql, join, null

How deals with MySQL `JOIN` deal with `NULL` values. Being that most address do not have a second line address, there are many NULL values for address2. When I run the query to match up address based on address1, address2 and zip, the query will not return positive matched of when only address1, and zip match.  I have ensured that both tables have a value of `NULL` for address2, when they are NULL. So basically to run the query I run two queries.

```
UPDATE target t
JOIN pl2.site2 s ON t.address1=s.address1 AND t.zip5=s.zip5 
SET t.idsite=s.idsite
WHERE t.address2 IS NULL AND s.address2 IS NULL;

UPDATE target t
JOIN pl2.site2 s ON t.address1=s.address1  AND t.address2=s.address2 AND t.zip5=s.zip5 
SET t.idsite=s.idsite;
```

Not really a hard work around.  Just trying to get more into the science of how the SQL works. Maybe there was another solution, I don't want to set the columns=''(blank) where they are NULL either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options to join the null fields.  One is to use `COALESCE` which converts the null values to blanks for the comparison:

```
UPDATE target t
JOIN pl2.site2 s ON 
    t.address1=s.address1 AND 
    COALESCE(t.address2,'')=COALESCE(s.address2,'') AND 
    t.zip5=s.zip5 
SET t.idsite=s.idsite;
```

Another option would be to use `OR` in the `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE target t
JOIN pl2.site2 s ON 
    t.address1=s.address1 AND 
    t.zip5=s.zip5 AND
    ((t.address2=s.address2) OR (t.address2 IS NULL AND s.addresss2 IS NULL))
SET t.idsite=s.idsite;
```